# Convert tree-like structure formatted as a string using indentations to a list of paths

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, recursion

I have a string like this:

```
Given_String = """\
Shoes
Fruits
 Red
  Apple
  Cherry
 !
 Yellow
  Banana
  Grapes
   Small
   Big
  !
 !
!
"""
```

I want to convert it into a list of path strings:

```
["Shoes",
"Fruits/Red/Apple",
"Fruits/Red/Cherry",
"Fruits/Yellow/Banana",
"Fruits/Yellow/Grapes/Small",
"Fruits/Yellow/Grapes/Big"]
```

I tried removing the '!' and replacing front spaces with "/", but I couldn't find any way.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 .. that said, you might start with the [`.splitlines()` string method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines)

Comment: Iterate on `Given_String.splitlines()`. Keep a list representing the current path and corresponding indentations. When you arrive on a new line, find whether its indentation is equal, more, or less than the previous indentation, and modify the current path accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `"!"` is a good idea: they only provide redundant information. But the spaces cannot just be replaced with slashes. Instead keep track of the current path in the form of a list, but always truncate that path so that the number of items in that path does not exceed the number of spaces you have in front of the current text.

Here is a generator function that does that. Note that it relies on the fact that your indentation happens with one space at a time:

```
def get_paths(lines):
    path = []
    for line in lines.splitlines():
        content = line.lstrip()
        if content.rstrip() not in "!":
            indent = len(line) - len(content)
            if indent < len(path):
                yield "/".join(path)
            path[indent:] = [content]
    if path:
        yield "/".join(path)
```

If you cannot rely on a consistent indentation, but the indentation  could increase with two spaces and sometimes three, ...etc, then you need to cope with that:

```
def get_paths(lines):
    path = []
    indents = [0]
    for line in lines.splitlines():
        content = line.lstrip()
        if content.rstrip() not in "!":
            indent = len(line) - len(content)
            while indent < indents[-1]:
                indents.pop()
            if indent > indents[-1]:
                indents.append(indent)
            elif path:
                yield "/".join(path)
            path[len(indents)-1:] = [content]
    if path:
        yield "/".join(path)
```

Example use:

```
s = """
Shoes
Fruits
 Red
  Apple
  Cherry
 !
 Yellow
  Banana
  Grapes
   Small
   Big
  !
 !
!
"""

result = list(get_paths(s))
print(result)
```

Comment: Its working great. But it returns extra unnecessary paths also. Like,
`['Shoes', 'Fruits', 'Fruits/Red', 'Fruits/Red/Apple', 'Fruits/Red/Cherry', 'Fruits/Yellow', 'Fruits/Yellow/Banana', 'Fruits/Yellow/Grapes', 'Fruits/Yellow/Grapes/Small', 'Fruits/Yellow/Grapes/Big'].`  

Only required,
`["Shoes",
"Fruits/Red/Apple",
"Fruits/Red/Cherry",
"Fruits/Yellow/Banana",
"Fruits/Yellow/Grapes/Small",
"Fruits/Yellow/Grapes/Big"]`

Comment: So you only want paths to the "leaves" of the tree?

Comment: Yes. I want only the paths to the leaves.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is tagged 'recursion', below is my obligatory attempt at a recursive solution:

```
def get_paths(lines, indentation=0):
    paths = []

    while lines:
        line = lines[0]

        if (path := line.lstrip()) == "!":
            return paths

        if (indent := len(line) - len(path)) > indentation:
            path = paths.pop()

            for sub_path in get_paths(lines, indent):
                paths.append(path + "/" + sub_path)
        else:
            paths.append(path)

        lines.pop(0)

    return paths

print("\n".join(get_paths(Given_String.splitlines())))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
% python3 test.py
Shoes
Fruits/Red/Apple
Fruits/Red/Cherry
Fruits/Yellow/Banana
Fruits/Yellow/Grapes/Small
Fruits/Yellow/Grapes/Big
%
```